# Backbone view optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js

I'm using backbone js in my Project, I'm struck in a small confusion with views.

I'm having these 2 views. After writing them i am in a confusion whether i'm in right path or not. The reason for my doubt is that the code was looking almost the same except that the el in which the view is rendered and the template that is used in the view.

Will this type of code effect the performance?? can I optimize it ?

**code:**

```
Project.views.list = Backbone.View.extend({
    // The DOM Element associated with this view
    el: '.lists-section-content',
    itemView: function(x){
        return new Project.views.list(x);
    },
    // View constructor
    initialize: function(payload) {
        this.data = payload.data;
        this.colStr = payload.colStr;
        this.render();
    },
    events: {

    },
    render: function() {
        sb.renderXTemplate(this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you be better to provide `el` value at first element of tree initialization, otherwise all views will try to use same DOM element(s):

```
var myTreeRoot= new Project.views.list({
  el: '.lists-section-content',
  data: payload.data,
  colStr: payload.colStr
});
```

After this you'll need to modify initialize function a little to utilize [options argument](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-152) of [view constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

```
// View constructor
initialize: function(options) {
    this.data = options.data;
    this.colStr = options.colStr;
    this.render();
},
```

And finally answering to your question, no this way it will not affect performance. You just need to track leaf views inside parent view and remove them with parent, it's needed to avoid memory leaks. Here is example of cleanup (all leaf views collected with `this.subViews` array and removed on parent removal):

```
Project.views.list = Backbone.View.extend({
    // The DOM Element associated with this view
    itemView: function(x){
        var view = new Project.views.list(x)
        this.subViews.push(view)
        this.$('.item-container:first').append(view.el)
    },
    remove: function() {
        _.invoke(this.subViews, 'remove')
        return Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments)
    },
    // View constructor
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.data = options.data;
        this.subViews = [];
        this.colStr = options.colStr;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        sb.renderXTemplate(this);
        return this;
    }
});
```